# FF6 CSS Javascript MozBorderRadius not working

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to set `MozBorderRadius` via JavaScript in FF6 but it doesn't seems to work. If I use `WebkitBorderRadius` on Safari it works.

`that.element.style.WebkitBorderRadius = '10px';`      <- works in Safari

`that.element.style.MozBorderRadius = '10px';`         <- does not work in FF6

Could someone confirm this?

**EDIT :**

FF5 same problem.

Something like this is working ok: `that.element.style.width = '200px';`

Comment: Try `that.elment.style.borderRadius="5px"`- this worked for me.

Comment: @aleks-g as     Doesn't work either. However, if I use setAttribute('style', '-moz-border-radius: 10px') it works but it is not what I want.

Comment: Strange... I just cut everything out leaving two lines in my test.html file: `<div id='div1' style='height: 40px;border:solid 1px blue'>This is my test</div>` and `<script type='test/javascript'>document.getElementById('div1').style.borderRadius = '10px';</script>` - and it works just fine

Comment: @aleks if he copy pasted your code **and** he's actually using in his code `that.element`, it won't work because you typed "elment" instead.

Comment: @Knu thanks for pointing out.  I was re-typing that line rather than copy-paste.  The second comment was a clean copy-paste from a test file.

Comment: @aleks You are right, borderRadius seems to work on FF. I think I have tested borderRadius on Safari by mistake which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prefix in `-moz-border-radius`* properties [was dropped](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=451134).
You will have to add `that.element.style.borderRadius` to support all modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what [MozillaDev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius) says: *In Gecko 2.0 -moz-border-radius is renamed to border-radius. -moz-border-radius is supported as an alias for a transitional period (at least until the next version of Gecko). In order to conform to the CSS3 standard, Gecko 2.0.*

I tend to use this service for CSS: http://border-radius.com/.
Maybe consider [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for the task of styling.

Best of luck!